# Receiving model in api controller from api call in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I can do this in asp.net but it does not work for asp.net core.

i have a view ad I call a JavaScript function that takes the model of that view and calls my api controller.

When i set a break-point before my api call I can see the values of the model and the api controller method does get invoked.

But, the model object received by the controller is always null?

View

```
@model InformedWorker.Services.Models.Registration
@inject IJsonHelper Json;


<div class="row" style="display:none" id="divRegistration">
<div class="col-xs-6">
    <div class="well">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="EmailAddress" class="control-label"></label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="EmailAddress" name="EmailAddress" value="@Model.EmailAddress" required="" title="Please enter you username" placeholder="example@gmail.com">
            <span class="help-block"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Password" class="control-label">Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="Password" name="Password" value="@Model.Password" required="" title="Please enter your password">
            <span class="help-block"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="ConfirmPassword" class="control-label"></label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="ConfirmPassword" name="ConfirmPassword" value="@Model.ConfirmPassword" required="" title="Please confirm your password">
        </div>
        <div id="registerErrorMsg" class="alert alert-error" style="display:none">Invalid registration</div>
        <a onclick="RegisterProxy();" class="btn btn-success btn-block">Register</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6">
    <p class="lead">Already Registered?</p>
    <p><a onclick="showLogInPage();" class="btn btn-info btn-block">LogIn</a></p>
</div
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    function RegisterProxy() {
        var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(Model));
        Register(model);
    }
</script>
```

my site.js

function Register(model) {
    try {

```
    $('#registerErrorMsg').html('');

    var uri = '/api/Registration';

    $.ajax({
        url: uri,
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: model,
        success: function (result) {
            alert('success');
        }
    });
}
catch (err) {
    $("#registerErrorMsg").css("display", "block");
    $('#registerErrorMsg').html(err);
}
return false;

[Route("api/Registration")]
public class Registration : Controller
{
    // POST api/values
    [HttpPost]
    public void Post([FromBody]Registration value)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: What is your model and controller method (and are you just posting back the original unchanged model that you sent to the view)?

Comment: And you need to remove `contentType: 'application/json',` (or `stringify()` the data)

Comment: @StephenMuecke so sorry was a away from pc.  Added controller to question. Sorry had forgot to add. thanks

Comment: @StephenMuecke the model values have been changed

Comment: What do you mean _the model values have changed_? - `@Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(Model))` is the original model - not anything that has been edited in the view so what is the point of this. And you still have not shown the model

Comment: @StephenMuecke well the view receives the model.  The user then adds their name and password to the form and post back.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I can put the model up. It is quite basic. I was focusing on passing a model data back to controller It could be any model.